# serverspec using environment variables in Rakefile

Tags: serverspec

Serverspec is used to check on several servers. Therefore the recommend structure of roles is used:

`|-- Rakefile
 |-- spec
    |-- app
    |   -- ruby_spec.rb
    |-- base
    |   -- users_and_groups_spec.rb
    |-- db
    |   -- mysql_spec.rb
    |-- proxy
    |   -- nginx_spec.rb
    |-- spec_helper.rb`

To read the data and structure I use a yaml-file.

On the [serverspec website](http://serverspec.org/advanced_tips.html) is in the Rakefile inside the Raketask the following:
`ENV['TARGET_HOST'] = host`

Why should I set the host as an environment variable? Wouldn't a local one be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `spec helper` uses it to target hosts for the `net-ssh` gem. You can refactor the host targeting code in the `spec_helper` to not even use it if you want and then just use `host_inventory` for the hostname.

Note the following:

https://github.com/mizzy/serverspec/blob/master/lib/serverspec/setup.rb#L276
https://github.com/mizzy/serverspec/blob/master/lib/serverspec/setup.rb#L292

Despite the anonymous downvote, this is absolutely the correct answer.